# writing a check program in python for other python files

Tags: python

I am writing a check.py file which reads a file that maps a python file to an output. That file looks something like this

```
001.py 233168
002.py 4613732
```

This means 001.py when ran should print out 233168. What is the best way to capture stdout from 00*.py? Overriding stdout and using execfile? or using a subprocess?

I have never done anything like this before, but it seems like

```
  subprocess.check_output
```

does exactly what I want, is there a more appropriate way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subprocess. That way the script being executed cannot disrupt the calling script too badly.